# SpriteKit Jumping and moving issues

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm fairly new to swift, and have been working on a game for fun, and i'm running into something I can't quite get my head around.

When the run button is pressed, the character moves forward with the following function

```
func move(dt: CGFloat) {
  position.x += moveRate * dt
}
```

And when the jump button is pressed, the character jumps with the following function

```
func jump() {
  physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: jumpRate))
  run(jumpAnimation!)
}
```

both work fine, but consider this senario. The player is running, and then they jump while still moving. While in the air, the player releases the move button and the player's x position stops dead. This obviously feels very unnatural, and i would like the player's x position to ease out.

Now i have also played with moving the character with `physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 1000, dy: 0))` which would give that effect, but he seems to just gain more and more speed and you don't get a constant rate or "max speed" so to speak.

Could anybody share some insight with me? I'd love to learn anything I can about spritekit and game development in general. Thanks!

Comment: From what I've seen, changing position manually at the same time while using forces never worked well. Try to use either just forces or change node's position by affecting on its position property. Also, apply force should be called within update: method, every frame (unlike applyImpulse method).

Comment: Even changing velocity vector directly while using forces and impulses will play nicely, so maybe you can play with that to...

Comment: been playing with the physicsBody a lot more on all of the objects. It's finicky it seems but i am achiving a better result with `applyForce` and `applyImpluse`. What do you mean by "changing velocity vector directly"???

Comment: When you apply forces or impulses to a physics body, you actually change its velocity vector (physicsBody.velocity) over time. If you do something like physicsBody.velocity.dx = someValue or physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(dx,dy) you change it directly and instantly. So it depends on your game what kind of effect you are trying to achieve - more natural (eg. using applyForce) or something else...

Comment: For example, in old platformer games, there were no physics, so characters were moving with instant and,  in many games, at constant speed :) Today, applyForce do all that physics calculation work so character will not start walking immediately with its desired speed, but rather it will gradually speed up so everything will look more natural. If you want that old style type of moving objects, then change velocity directly .

Comment: If everything else is OK but you just have a problem with the character's speed continuously increasing, look into enforcing a maximum in 'didApplyConstraints' or 'didFinishUpdate'. Unfortunately, there is no SKConstraint for velocity.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to set the velocity instead of setting the X position. When setting the position you bypass all the physics behaviors.
You should also try to set it only when you actually press a button.

```
func move(dt: CGFloat) {
    if Math.abs(moveRate) > 0.1 { // If player initiates movement. You can increase the value 0.1 if you want to filter move values
        velocity = CGVector(dx: moveRate, dy: veloxity.dy)
    }
}
```

It your character moves indefinitely like in space, `linearDamping` will be useful. it's used to simulate air friction, so values closer to 1 means more friction and values closer to 0 means less friction.

```
linearDamping = 0.85
```

Also, this way, `moveRate` isn't `dt` dependent but it should be lowered.

---

Try it, **I haven't tested it yet**, but that's basically how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two schools of thought on platformer game "physics".

1. Don't use physics, do everything with positional incrementation.
2. Do everything with physics, since positional changes mess up physics

---

*Since you're using physics for jumping, and physics jumping is fun:*

There are three ways to create movement in a physics system:

1. Set the velocity as and when required. This is what Crazyrems is suggesting
2. Apply impulses as needed to increase and decrease rates of movement
3. Apply forces over time that increase or decrease rates of movement
4. Use fields to induce motion (too complex for this, and messy, but fun)

What you're attempting, with your `physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 1000, dy: 0))` is the application of force over time. Number 3 in the list above. The longer you continue applying this force the faster the character moves.

Each of these techniques can be made to work, but they all need compensation for their various limitations and methodologies of simulation.

In the case of your approach, you need monitor speed and to set a maximum speed. Having reached maximum speed, if the player is still holding the button, only provide enough force to maintain speed (assuming you're using some form of constant resistance to slow the character).

Monitoring speed combined with force-over-time creates interesting acceleration trait possibilities - like very strong initial acceleration and then taper off acceleration as the player nears their maximum speed.

Slowing down when the player releases the button is the next focus. In all these approaches you need something that slows the player. This can be the application of opposing forces, or the use of friction or damping, as provided by the physics engine.